# Create a custom 3d perspective projection matrix

Tags: matrices, geometry, linear-transformations

I'm working a simple program that renders 're-projected' 3d scenes, and this programs requires a projection matrix that starts at $P_{0}$, and whose frustum edges touch 4 co-planar points ($P_{1}$ $...$ $P_{4}$).

[Starting data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwrMF.png)

[Matrix Frustum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOC7G.png)

After applying the matrix to each vertex it should look like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJlHp.png)

How can I create this matrix? Do I need more information?

Comment: I think you need at least a disparity information or depth map.

Comment: Like the near and far plane?

Comment: I mean, we need stereo images or a distance map from the cam to each point of the subject.

Comment: The only thing I need is a way of calculating a projection matrix that has a specific frustum. I know it can be done using 4 points and maybe other camera settings: https://www.facebook.com/b2bk.fr/videos/quad-reprojection/2844664065854461/

Comment: I guess the transformation is based on the fact that the subject is in rectangular form?

Comment: You might get better answers at https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com